# List RGB Values from DominantColors

Tags: list-manipulation, color

I have taken an screenshot using the `GUIScreenShot` function from `GUIKit` and then evaluated the dominant colours in the image. I now want to have a list of the RGB values for these colours.

[image]

As you can see at the bottom of my notebook I have done `ColorConvert[DominantColors[image, 4], "RGB"] // InputForm` which gives the following output

```
{RGBColor[0.9981899992636899, 0.998221989435874, 0.9981360066982335], 
RGBColor[0.04255544957210438, 0.11839631683320873, 0.30599384848307215], 
RGBColor[0.9260920245210382, 0.9256815319162999, 0.9248727382341635], 
RGBColor[0.12685956345889995, 0.484438597690588, 0.5010599338073215]}
```

How would I extract a list of the RGB values from this? e.g. in the form

```
{{0.9981899992636899, 0.998221989435874, 0.9981360066982335},{0.04255544957210438, 0.11839631683320873, 0.30599384848307215}...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List@@@rgblist
```

will do what you want

Comment: works perfectly! could you explain what the @@@ means though? (or at least the name of the function so I can look it up in the docs)

Comment: @FlamingSquirrel You'll notice that you can look up `@@@` directly in the docs, if you actually try...

Comment: Alternatively, @FlamingSquirrel, highlight `@@@` in your notebook and press F1.